# call a function before method call

Tags: php

Design question / PHP:
I have a class with methods.
I would like to call to an external function anytime when any of the methods within the class is called.
I would like to make it generic so anytime I add another method, the flow works with this method too.

Simplified example:

```
<?php

function foo()
{
    return true;
}

class ABC {
    public function a()
    {
        echo 'a';
    }
    public function b()
    {
        echo 'b';
    }
}

?>
```

I need to call to foo() before a() or b() anytime are called.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any necessary for that. It seems to be like a `constructor` in a `class`

Comment: Use the decorator pattern with hooks to the `__call` and `__callStatic` to intercept any method call and execute your function before doing the real call.

Comment: @didierc can you please paste a sudo code here as it is not understandable for many people beginners like me.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I have no doubt you'll be able to figure it out by yourself with a little bit of time. Anyway, my answer is posted.

Answer (score 9):

Protect your methods so they're not directly accessible from outside the class, then use the magic [__call()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) method to control access to them, and execute them after calling your foo()

```
function foo()
{
    echo 'In pre-execute hook', PHP_EOL;
    return true;
}

class ABC {
    private function a()
    {
        echo 'a', PHP_EOL;
    }
    private function b($myarg)
    {
        echo $myarg, ' b', PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if(!method_exists($this, $method)) {
            throw new Exception("Method doesn't exist");
        }
        call_user_func('foo');
        call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $args);
    }
}

$test = new ABC();
$test->a();
$test->b('Hello');
$test->c();
```

Comment: It does not work if ABC class is extended and ABC class uses parent class method. It gets to call_user_func_array and generates method not found an exception.